# Monsters under my Minecraft bed!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am scared of monsters in Minecraft.  Does peaceful difficulty make them go away? Please help, I don't like creepers, zombies, skeletons, or spiders!  Please help!

Answer (score 5):

**YES**

Peaceful difficulty does the following:

1. Stops monsters from Spawning and remove any mobs in-game already
2. Your hunger bar will not diminish
3. And will heal your health bar quicker than Easy or higher

Comment: Re: 2: I thought your hunger bar didn't diminish at all on peaceful (though I could be wrong).

Comment: @JohntheGreen You are correct. Edited.

Comment: Apparently I was incorrect about the hunger bar.  I'll need to read the wiki for confirmed knownlegde

Comment: Here you go: ["The Food Bar never depletes"](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Difficulty)

Comment: @JohntheGreen I meant that I need to read the wiki before posting.

Answer (score 0):

Switching to peaceful will remove all hostile mobs from the world and will prevent subsequent ones from spawning.